# Error access to database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Please explain to me differents between

```
private boolean inUse(JDBCTemplates jdbc, BigInteger firmwareId) {
               String query = "select * from references ref " +
                "where ref.attr_id = 9 " +
                "and ref.reference = ?";
        try { 
               s = (String) jdbc.selectForObject(query....);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               log.info(e.toString());
            }
        return ...;
}
```

and

```
private boolean inUse(JDBCTemplates jdbc, BigInteger firmwareId) {
              String query = "select * from references ref " +
              "where ref.attr_id = 9 " +
              "and ref.reference =" + firmwareId;
        try { 
              s = (String) jdbc.selectForObject(query....);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              log.info(e.toString());
            }
        return ...;
}
```

In the second case, I get an access error to the database (**jdbc.DataAccessException: Error due to access to database**), and in the first case everything works.

Comment: Please show the complete error!

Comment: Post complete code. Your snippets are meaningless without seeing the complete code and how you're executing them.

Comment: jdbc.DataAccessException: Error due to access to database:

Comment: in the first case you have `?`, in the second you just append `firmwareId` (bad). I assume, your code is trying to change `?` with the firmwareId in the second case, but can't find the question mark, since you never put it there.

Comment: What error do you get? The first case is the correct way, you should never write parameter values directly in query string. You should use parameters like the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to modify your code this way, pay attention to the string query and the parameter:

```
private boolean inUse(JDBCTemplates jdbc, BigInteger firmwareId) {
          String query = "select * from references ref " +
          "where ref.attr_id = 9 " +
          "and ref.reference ='" + firmwareId+"'";//Here might be the error
    try { 
          s = (String) jdbc.selectForObject(query....);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.info(e.toString());
        }
    return ...;
```

}

try this and let us know if it works or not, so that we can try something else